# Unable to install Python 3.6 - version already exists

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

I recently was given a new work laptop for a summer internship and am having some troubles installing Python 3.6. Whenever I go to install the file, I receive this error:

[image]

After going to the control panel to try to uninstall whatever version is currently there, I find a 3.6 version listed in a (now deleted) Anaconda3 folder. When I try to uninstall that version, I receive this error:

[image]

I'm stuck in a bit of an endless loop here, any idea how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Also, if this question is in the wrong section, apologies. This is the first installation question I've ever had.

Comment: That means there is no *standard Python installation by that version*. Anaconda is a custom distribution, use the Anaconda uninstaller for that. It may be that the installation is rather messed up however, leaving only Windows registry entries in place.

Comment: There's no Anaconda Program left in my Control Panel or anywhere that I can find either. I would've uninstalled but there's nothing there for me to uninstall. This is where I can't seem to figure out what to do next.